# Python merge multiple columns single dataframe

Tags: python

I have a single data frame with 4 columns that each contain YES or NO values in each row. I would like to create a new column in the data frame that reads those columns and places the name of the column in the row if one of the 4 original columns has a YES.

To be clear:

```
data = {'w':['YES','NO','NO','NO'],
        'x':['NO','YES','NO','NO'],
        'y':['NO','NO','YES','NO'],
        'z':['NO','NO','NO','YES']}
```

I'd like a fifth column ('a') that shows 'w','x','y',or 'z', depending on if the column reads 'YES' or 'NO'. So, column A would read ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'].

I've tried a number of things, but I'm new to Python and am a bit stuck. Even a pointer towards the right package to think about would be enough to help me figure it out!

Thank you!

1/25/2018 UPDATE: Here is a crude function made to help achieve this goal. I'm certain there is a more elegant way to get this done, but this ultimately worked:

```
def my_function_with_args(w, x, y, z): 
if 'YES' in w:a="W"
elif 'YES' in x:a="X"
elif 'YES' in y:a="Y"
elif 'YES' in z:a="Z"
else:a="NONE"
print(a)
return a

mylist=[]
for i, row in data.iterrows():
myW=row['W']
myX=row['X']
myY=row['Y']
myZ=row['Z']
myresult=my_function_with_args(myW,myX,myY,myZ)
mylist.append(myresult)
```

Comment: What was your best attempt and what was the problem with it? Also please specify: Can there be more than one 'YES' per column? What should happen in this case? How large is your dictionary? Are numpy or pandas solutions an option?

Comment: My best attempt was flailing around trying to use merge functions, trying to set up the yes/no's as boolean 1/0. I was trying to use by numpy and pandas, but couldn't find anything in my internet searches. There's a lot of information about combining two separate dataframes, but not a lot about combining two or more columns in a dataframe into one column based on yes/no.

The data should only produce one YES per column. Its the Dodgers data set from Miller's book.

Comment: Update: I've tried using groupby and making a variable that is a count of all the "yes" instances in the different columns but I'm really striking out. Any help would be appreciated! Like I mentioned, even if its just a package I could look at!

Comment: Maybe you want to update your question with this additional information?

Comment: I'm sorry people did not find this thread helpful and it got downvoted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data are consistent as you say, always contains only one `'YES'` per column, the rest is `'NO'` and they have the same number of columns for each dictionary key, then you can create a list of the dictionary keys directly:

```
data = {'w': ['NO', 'NO', 'YES','NO' ],
        'x': ['NO', 'YES','NO', 'NO' ],
        'y': ['YES','NO', 'NO', 'NO' ],
        'z': ['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES']}

res = sorted(data, key = lambda k: data[k], reverse = True)

>>>['y', 'x', 'w', 'z']
```

This obviously won't work, if there are other list elements than `'YES'/'NO'` e.g. `ZZ`. In this case, you could also use

```
res = sorted(data, key = lambda k: data[k].index("YES"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work:

```
data = {'w':['YES','NO','NO','NO'],
        'x':['NO','YES','NO','NO'],
        'y':['NO','NO','YES','NO'],
        'z':['NO','NO','NO','YES']}

# Initialize a list of the right size
l = ['' for _ in range(len(data['w']))]

# Loop over keys and items simultaneously
for k, i in data.items():
    try:  # If index doesn't find 'YES' in a list it throws a ValueError
        l[i.index('YES')] = k
    except ValueError:
        continue  # Nothing to see here just go on with your life

# Store the list as part of the initial data
data['a'] = l
```